# Locating region between a confidence interval in data using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, confidence-interval

I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

The code to generate this plot:

```
CI=4.5
data=pandas.DataFrame([3,5,1,2,3,4,5,6])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot([CI]*len(data),'--')
plt.ylabel('y data',fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('x data',fontsize=15)
plt.title('example data',fontsize=15)
```

I can also interpolate the data using scipy:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f=interp1d(x_data,y_data,kind='linear')
x_interp=numpy.linspace(min(x_data),max(x_data), num=100*len(x_data), endpoint=True)
y_interp=f(x_interp)        
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_interp,y_interp)
```

The green line represents a confidence interval. I need to programmatically locate the x values where the y values cross this confidence internal. But, the complication is that since this is a confidence interval I need to get the values that cross the green line in both directions: 
[image]

i.e. I need the x values where the y data crosses the red arrows whilst excluding those at the black arrow. I've tried many variations of subtracting the confidence interval from the interpolated data as well as taking the absolute values but I still cannot isolate the confidence interval.

Comment: A confidence interval is a range of values, e.g., `lower_bound = CI - something; upper_bound = CI + something_else`. I also don't understand why the black arrow is, well, black, while the other are treated as red.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you want everything above the green line?

Comment: @Reti43 The arrows are simply for illustration - as is the data (because giving the real data here is less feasible). In the real data yes, the CI's would be parameter estimate +/- confidence interval. But they are non-symmetrical due to non-linearity.

Comment: @armatita - Usually yes, but the data i'm using is the result of sum of squares not log-likelihood objective function (which would be above, not below the green line). Either way, the computational task at hand is the same whether above or below the green line. Thanks for responding

Comment: Synthetic data for the sake of demonstration are fine. But any aspects of your question that don't represent your actual problem are distracting or confusing. Quite explicitly, do you want the x values for which the y values lie within a specific range, i.e., +/- of some mean value?

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity Reti, Yes, I want to x values for which the y values lie within a specific range. This range however is determined by where the y values cross the green line (not +/- some value because of non-linearities in the model). Parameters that fall within these boundaries are acceptable parameters (for an ODE model). Those that are above get rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

> I want to x values for which the y values lie within a specific range

it seems you're simply looking for a mask. If you give numpy a relational statement, e.g. `my_array > x`, it will return a boolean array with `True` for any indices where this relation is satisfied. And if you pass such a mask to an array for indexing, it'll return the values where this mask is `True`. For example,

```
In [2]: a = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 9, 4])

In [3]: a > 2
Out[3]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [4]: a[a > 2]
Out[4]: array([3, 5, 9, 4])
```

So, to find the `x` values where `f(x)` lies within a specific range, find the indices where `f(x)` is in the desired range and filter your `x` based on that mask.

```
# multiplication between 1s and 0s acts like logical AND
mask = (y_interp >= lower_bound) * (y_interp <= upper_bound)
accepted_parameters = x_interp[mask]
```

Comment: Instead of `*`, you could also use elementwise `AND` with `&`, which would achieve the same thing.